# How to remove MacOS and install Ubuntu

Tags: startup

I have an Intel based Macbook pro and I want to get rid of MacOS. Now this video by [At Tech](https://youtu.be/LFgM5es3Aro) says you can just boot from usb which has Ubuntu and then clean hard disk i.e. `Erase disk and install Ubuntu` this is all you need

Now my question is: On Startup will my macbook automatically boot me in `Ubuntu` or I need to install some custom recovery like `refind` or something else?

model: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) - https://support.apple.com/kb/SP704

Comment: I recommend creating a bootable macOS installer USB disk first, in case you ever want to convert it back (even if it's just to sell it when you replace it). Instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372), but missing the step that you should start by formatting it with a GUID partition table (GPT).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I have always used the Master Boot Record scheme without any problems. The step you refer to is probably missing because it does not mater whether Master Boot Record or GUID Partition Map scheme is selected when erasing.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Interesting; I've had trouble with it in the past, and just always formatted them GPT since then. Maybe Apple added MBR support to the firmware at some point, and I didn't notice.

Comment: @GordonDavisson can't you re-install macos from recovery(online download and install macos)? by doing cmd+r ?? reinstall macos??

Comment: @abhimanyuaryan it's possible to reinstall via Online Recovery, though it's a pain and personality, it's never worked for me when the internal drive isn't correctly formatted as APFS.

Comment: @At0mic Exactly. There are a bunch of things that can go wrong with Internet Recovery; a bootable installer disk is way more reliable.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I didn't get your GPT section. Before you make a bootable pendrive with macos you format the pendrive as GPT? If yes...what format fat32? or macos journ?

Comment: @abhimanyuaryan It needs to be in Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format, but IIRC the `createinstallmedia` program will fix that part automatically if it's in FAT32 or something like that (it deletes & recreates the volume in the correct format). It's just the partition table that it doesn't take care of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Grub boot files installed by Ubuntu are compatible with the Mac Startup Manager. While the Mac should automatically boot Ubuntu, you can also select to always boot from Ubuntu by holding down the option key at startup, then selecting the icon label `EFI Boot`. After doing so, the Mac should boot Ubuntu by default.

I assume here your MacBook Pro is a newer model that would capable of 64 bit EFI booting Ubuntu and have at least 4 GB of memory. If not, then you should update your question.

I also assume here your Mac does not have the T2 chip. If your Mac has the T2 chip, then you have to [remove Secure Boot and allow External Boot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198). Some releases of Ubuntu can not be installed on the internal drive of newer Intel Macs. If this is the case with your Mac, then you will need to install to an USB drive.

You can install the rEFInd boot manager if you wish, but consider this. The firmware on the Mac logic board contains a boot loader and boot manager. Ubuntu will by default install Grub, which is also a boot loader and boot manager. (Although in this case, the boot manager will operate silently.) Installing a rEFInd as a third boot manager is not necessary.

Comment: yes I have a newer version of Macbook Pro with 16GB Ram

Comment: No my mac doesn't have the T2 Chip. It's older than 2018

Comment: abhimanyuaryan: Could you edit your question and include model year and maybe the screen size? This would help narrow down your Mac's specs from [all the MacBook Pro models](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/index-macbookpro.html) made.

Comment: done I have added model